# VIM highlight matching begin/end

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting, verilog, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to find a plugin that will highlight the matching begin/end statements with Verilog. VIM has it working with curly braces /brackets but it does not work with its begin/end. I want VIM to highlight the correct begin to the correct end.

Comment: How about [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1586)?

Comment: And [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4743)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, your best bet is using matchit. This script is part of vim runtime and can easily be loaded by adding the following line to your .vimrc:

```
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

The standard Verilog filetype plugin already includes the matchit configuration you require:

```
" Let the matchit plugin know what items can be matched.
if exists("loaded_matchit")
  let b:match_ignorecase=0
  let b:match_words=
    \ '\<begin\>:\<end\>,' .
    \ '\<case\>\|\<casex\>\|\<casez\>:\<endcase\>,' .
    \ '\<module\>:\<endmodule\>,' .
    \ '\<if\>:\<else\>,' .
    \ '\<function\>:\<endfunction\>,' .
    \ '`ifdef\>:`else\>:`endif\>,' .
    \ '\<task\>:\<endtask\>,' .
    \ '\<specify\>:\<endspecify\>'
endif
```

This way you can match the begin/end using `%` key, as you probably already do for parentheses and such.

This is not exactly what you were looking for, in the sense that although it allows you to find the matching end of a begin it does not highlight it for you. I did some research and apparently there's a [code snippet around for that](http://objectmix.com/editors/377087-matchit-plugin-highlighting.html); and there's someone who already transformed that code into a plugin, which is named [hl_matchit](https://github.com/vimtaku/hl_matchit.vim). Don't forget to check this plugin's help page:

```
:help hl_matchit.txt
```

Please note that the Verilog filetype plugin included in vim installation does not support the `ifndef` and `elsif` clauses introduced in Verilog 2001. If you require this then I suggest that you also install the verilog_systemverilog.vim plugin already mentioned before, but use the [fork](https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim) I am improving which includes the afore mentioned updates, as well as other fixes/improvements.

Comment: Restart from scratch. Install the plugin linked at the bottom and hl_matchit plugin, also linked.

Comment: This `match_words` does't included some original  match pairs defined in matchit, such as "\<if\>:\<endif\>" .How could I preserve those pairs?

Comment: Don't you mean `ifdef`? But `b:match_words` is an editable string and you can modify it as it suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question. Have a look on a syntax file [systemverilog.vim](https://github.com/nachumk/systemverilog.vim/blob/master/syntax/systemverilog.vim) 25 line:

```
syntax region svCase matchgroup=svConditional start="\<case\|casex\|casez\>" end="\<endcase\>" contains=ALL
```

- `syntax` is a vim command (`:he syntax` for more explanation)
- `region` keyword for region
- `svCase` just name
- `matchgroup` - The syntax group to use for the following start or end pattern matches only.
- `start` and `end` - regexps for marking start and end syntax region
- `contains=ALL` means then all other groups will be accepted inside the region.

Hope that's you looking for.

Comment: That syntax command just controls who the conditionals are highlighted. The OP wants dynamic highlighting of the current matching keyword.

Comment: Explain. I think good start point is `:he matchit` and maybe [this question](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=290)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any plugin that does this, but you can probably derive that functionality from the related [html_MatchTag plugin](https://github.com/gregsexton/MatchTag), which implements this for HTML tags, by adapting to the Verilog filetype and replacing the corresponding regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Install the system verilog plugin: https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim

Install matchit `:he matchit`
and you are good to go!