# gvim Systemverilog syntax matching :is there way to match `ifdef `ifndef `else and `endif

Tags: vim, system-verilog, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have used standard SystemVerilog syntax packages but not able to match(with % move the cursor between) these strings. This is in the context of matchit function in Vim(https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39).
The problem seems to be with backtick.

I tried:

```
\u0060
```

and

```
`ifdef\>|`ifndef\>:`endif\>,
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I edited your post to hopefully show your code properly. If it's not correct then please fix as needed.

Comment: "Match" can mean quite a few things depending on the context. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: This is a mistake in https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1586 Systemverilog highlight package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a file that looks like this:

```
stuff
`ifdef
    some code
`endif
stuff
```

With the cursor on `` `ifdef `` (or `` `ifndef ``), you want to jump to `` `endif `` with `%` then back to `` `ifdef `` if you press `%` again. I'm also assuming you're using the matchit plugin.

Solution:

```
:let b:match_words='`ifdef\>\|`ifndef\>:`endif\>'
```

Notice that the `|` has to be escaped with a backslash. Also, you need quotation marks `'`. So the backticks were not the problem.

Comment: Thanks ! @ProgMetalSlug the `|` was not escaped with backslash. There are similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498221/vim-highlight-matching-begin-end. I would like to use the package provided by @Vitor